# "coords" function of "pROC" package returns different sensibility and specificity values than "confusionMatrix" function of "caret" package

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, proc, confusion-matrix

Hi everybody and thank you very much in advance for your help.

I have performed a random forest model for classification. Now I want to determine the best threshold to optimize specificity and sensibility.

I am confused because, as stated in the title, the "coords" function of "pROC" package returns different values than the "confusionMatrix" function of the "caret" package.

Below is the code :

```
# package import

library(caret)
library(pROC)

# data import

data <- read.csv2("denonciation.csv", check.names = F)

# data partition

validation_index <- createDataPartition(data$Denonc, p=0.80,list=FALSE)
validation <- data[-validation_index,]
entrainement <- data[validation_index,]

# handling class imbalance

set.seed (7)
up_entrainement <- upSample(x=entrainement[,-ncol(entrainement)],y=entrainement$Denonc)

# Cross validation setting

control <- trainControl(method ="cv", number=10, classProbs = TRUE)

# Model training

fit.rf_up <-train(Denonc~EMOTION+Agreabilite_classe+Conscienciosite_classe, data = up_entrainement, method="rf", trControl = control)

# Best threshold determination

roc <- roc(up_entrainement$Denonc, predict(fit.rf_up, up_entrainement, type = "prob")[,2])
    coords(roc, x="best", input = "threshold", best.method = "closest.topleft")

### The best threshold seems to be .36 with a specificity of .79 and a sensitivity of .73 ###

# Confusion matrix with the best threshold returned by "coords"

probsTest <- predict(fit.rf_up, validation, type = "prob")
threshold <- 0.36
predictions <- factor(ifelse(probsTest[, "denoncant"] > threshold, "denoncant", "non_denoncant"))
confusionMatrix(predictions, validation$Denonc)
```

Here the values are different :

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

                Reference
Prediction      denoncant non_denoncant
  denoncant           433          1380
  non_denoncant       386          1671

           Accuracy : 0.5437          
             95% CI : (0.5278, 0.5595)
No Information Rate : 0.7884          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

              Kappa : 0.0529          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

        Sensitivity : 0.5287          
        Specificity : 0.5477          
     Pos Pred Value : 0.2388          
     Neg Pred Value : 0.8123          
         Prevalence : 0.2116          
     Detection Rate : 0.1119          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.4685          
    Balanced Accuracy : 0.5382          

   'Positive' Class : denoncant
```

Please, could you tell me why the "coords" function of the "pROC" package returns false values?

Many thanks,

Baboune

Comment: If I am not mistaken you chose the cutoff value based on train data (data the model saw). What you should have done is to choose the cutoff value based on hold out predictions in re-sampling.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible issues here that I can see:

1. While training the model, the samples from the 2 classes are balanced by up-sampling the less numerous class: the best threshold resulting from the model is also calibrated on the same up-sampled dataset. That is not the case for the validation data set as far as I can see.
2. The two results give out model metrics on different sets (training and validation): while they are supposed to be close together for a RandomForest model, considering all the averaging that occurs under the hood, this doesn't mean the results will be exactly the same. It is very unlikely that a RandomForest model will over-fit the data, but it is possible if the data consists of a mixture of several different populations with different distributions of feature vectors and/or different feature-response relations, which may not always be uniformly distributed in the training and validation sets, even if you do randomly sample the data (i.e. the distribution may be same on average, but not for particular training-validation divides).

I think the first one is what is going wrong, but unfortunately, I can't test out your code, since it depends on the the file `denonciation.csv`.